# Is there an online tool for the declension of 3rd declension words?

Tags: declension, third-declension

I have a hard time remembering which words are attested with a -ium gentivie plural, which words can take an accusative in -im etc, so I was looking for an online tool to help me.

The Olivetti dictionary does not seem to be very reliable based on this example: https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-dictionary-flexion.php?parola=vis

Is Wiktionary the best I can find?

Comment: I use the Scriba Latin Dictionary. It's an app.

Comment: The imparisyllabic nouns make the genitive plural with "ium"(Dens, dentis/ Dentes, dentium)
And the parisyllac nouns make the genitive plural with "um"(Canis, canis/Canes, canum)

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças What about turris, turrium, nāvis, nāvium, etc?

Comment: Something called Exception?

Comment: I don't think those are exception. See [Allan and Greenough, especially 78](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-summary-i-stem-forms) for more rules.

Comment: (Or rather, it's far more complicated than just that.)

Answer (score 2):

Wiktionary is OK, although certainly not perfect (it makes use of templates to generate noun/adjective forms based on rules, so it's possible for them to be incorrect).

The accusative in *-im* is not that common. [Allen and Greenough §75](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-summary-i-stem-forms) gives a list (note: I think the claim there that -im would be expected to be the "regular case-ending" for i-stems is a bit uncertain), although it ends with "rarely in many other words".

Genitive plural *-ium* vs. *-um* is a real mess and I don't know of a really good way to look it up quickly. I think more than a handful of words might even not be attested at all in this form.